# Lemma for Powerfully Embedded Groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have a question about a step in a proof in Dixon's "Analytic Pro-P Groups" (p. 38):
Let $G$ a finite $p$-group with $p>2$. A subgroup $N$ is called powerfully embedded if $[N, G] \subset N^p$ holds.

My question refers to the red tagged line (see image below) in the proof of 2.2 (iv):

That's clear that we can find a $J \vartriangleleft G$ such that $N^p \leq J < M$ (therefore $J \neq M$) and $|M:J| =p$, but it's not clear to me how we get $J$ such that $N^p[N, W, W] \leq J$, or in other words why we have $N^p[N, W, W] \neq N^p[N, W]$ (I know that $[N, W, W] \neq [N, W]$ holds because $G$ nilpotent).

I tried to show that it follows from the third isomorphism theorem ($NH/N \cong H/(H \cup N)$ but till now it failed.

Here the image:

[image]